# Autowire SessionFactory without @Transactional in spring hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

Why should I use @Transactional to autowire SessionFactory for just a select query ?

Answer (score 1):

`@Transactional` is used for transaction and indicate that you need to have a transaction in the scope of your class of your method.

To Autowire SessionFactory, you need to use `@Autowire` annotation, but I think is not good idea to use SessionFactory everywhere, try to use Session in your DAO layers.

If you need to create a query just to READ no transaction is required.

Comment: But when I create a select query in a DAO class with no @Transactional annotation I get this error :
"Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread"